# elasticsearch prefix query for multiple words to solve the autocomplete use case

Tags: search, autocomplete, elasticsearch

How do I get elastic search to work to solve a simple autocomplete use case that has multiple words?

Lets say I have a document with the following title - Elastic search is a great search tool built on top of lucene.

So if I use the prefix query and construct it with the form -

```
{
    "prefix" : { "title" : "Elas" }
}
```

It will return that document in the result set.

However if I do a prefix search for

```
{
    "prefix" : { "title" : "Elastic sea" }
}
```

I get no results.

What sort of query do I need to construct so as to present to the user that result for a simple autocomplete use case.

Answer (score 19):

A prefix query made on `Elastic sea` would match a term like `Elastic search` in the index, but that doesn't appear in your index if you tokenize on whitespaces. What you have is `elastic` and `search` as two different tokens. Have a look at the [analyze api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze/) to find out how you are actually indexing your text.

Using a boolean query like in your answer you wouldn't take into account the position of the terms. You would get as a result the following document for example:

> Elastic model is a framework to store your Moose object and search
>   through them.

For auto-complete purposes you might want to make a phrase query and use the last term as a prefix. That's available out of the box using the match_phrase_prefix type in a [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/), which was made available exactly for your usecase:

```
{
    "match" : {
        "message" : {
            "query" : "elastic sea",
            "type" : "phrase_prefix"
        }
    }
}
```

With this query your example document would match but mine wouldn't since `elastic` is not close to `search` there.

Comment: I should have clarified and this is my mistake. The position of the terms is not important to me since I am only looking at titles and not against the entire description. Will the phrase_prefix query not bring back results if i searched for Elastic Moos in your example?

Comment: No it won't! The query I proposed takes into account the position of the terms and expands only the last one treating it as a prefix.

Answer (score 6):

To achieve that result, you will need to use a Boolean query. The partial word needs to be a prefix query and the complete word or phrase needs to be in a match clause. There are other tweaks available to the query like must should etc.. that can be applied as needed.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "name": "sea"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "elastic"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Little top: if the search terms just happen to end at word boundary(whitespace), don't insert prefix.